# Redefinition of module 'React' in React-RCTWebSocket.modulemap

Tags: reactjs, xcode, react-native, cocoapods, upgrade

Good day,

We have just upgraded `react-native` from `0.59.10` to `0.60.0`.
Mainly we have been following these guides:

https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.59.10&to=0.60.0

[https://mattoakes.net/react-native-upgrade-guides/upgrade-to-react-native-0.60](https://mattoakes.net/react-native-upgrade-guides/upgrade-to-react-native-0.60/)

When it comes to Android, the upgrade process was pretty straight-forward. But my team is **struggling quite a bit when doing the iOS side**.

After following those guides and solve some problems, we are facing one which we can not find any info about... We have been stuck in here for a while now.

So, the **problem is**: when we build the project, the next error appears. [image: ERROR IMAGE]

Reading about some similar topics, other people of the community suggested that we may be adding the same package twice either in the `Build Settings` or the `Build Phases` in our target in the XCode project. But I can not find any of it :/

I suspect that the error comes form our `Podfile`, but it looks good to me:

```
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.0'

use_modular_headers!

def pods()
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React'
  pod 'React-DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React'
  pod 'React-fishhook', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/fishhook'
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'React-RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/WebSocket'

  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
  pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec', :modular_headers => false
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec', :modular_headers => false
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec', :modular_headers => false
end

target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' do
  # Pods for OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension
  use_native_modules!
end

target 'XXX' do
  # Pods for xxx
  pods()
  
  target 'XXXTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
  
  use_native_modules!

  post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY'] = 'No'
      end
    end
  end

end
```

That's it, can anyone help us?

If there is anything you want me to attach in order to have more info about the error, do not hesitate to ask.

All advice is welcome :)

Comment: just a dump guess, have you done this step? https://github.com/react-native-community/upgrade-support/issues/14

Comment: Hey @Horst . Following the guide we went throw this step: `The next step is to remove the existing libraries from your Xcode project. The easiest way to do this is to open Xcode and delete the Libraries group in the left menu. Make sure you choose “Remove references” to avoid breaking your node modules.`. So the answer to your question is YES :/

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue with a package in my pods requiring i use the `use_modular_headers!`
setting.

This seems to cause conflicts in the react modules as its defining react twice. The fix for me was to add `:modular_headers => false` after each react package in the podfile. Here is my podfile for react version 0.60.6 as an example.

```
target ‘app’ do
  use_modular_headers!
  # Pods for RNDiffapp
  pod ‘React’, :path => ‘../node_modules/react-native/’
  pod ‘React-Core’, :path => ‘../node_modules/react-native/React’
  pod ‘React-DevSupport’, :path => ‘../node_modules/react-native/React’, :modular_headers => false
  pod ‘React-RCTActionSheet’, :path => ‘../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS’, :modular_headers => false
  pod ‘React-RCTAnimation’, :path => ‘../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation’, :modular_headers => false
  pod ‘React-RCTBlob’, :path => ‘../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob’, :modular_headers => false
  pod ‘React-RCTImage’, :path => ‘../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image’, :modular_headers => false
  pod ‘React-RCTLinking’, :path => ‘../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS’, :modular_headers => false
  pod ‘React-RCTNetwork’, :path => ‘../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network’, :modular_headers => false
  pod ‘React-RCTSettings’, :path => ‘../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings’, :modular_headers => false
  pod ‘React-RCTText’, :path => ‘../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text’, :modular_headers => false
  pod ‘React-RCTVibration’, :path => ‘../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration’, :modular_headers => false
  pod ‘React-RCTWebSocket’, :path => ‘../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/WebSocket’, :modular_headers => false
  pod ‘React-cxxreact’, :path => ‘../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact’, :modular_headers => false
  pod ‘React-jsi’, :path => ‘../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi’, :modular_headers => false
  pod ‘React-jsiexecutor’, :path => ‘../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor’, :modular_headers => false
  pod ‘React-jsinspector’, :path => ‘../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector’, :modular_headers => false
  pod ‘yoga’, :path => ‘../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga’, :modular_headers => false
  pod ‘DoubleConversion’, :podspec => ‘../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec’, :modular_headers => false
  pod ‘glog’, :podspec => ‘../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec’, :modular_headers => false
  pod ‘Folly’, :podspec => ‘../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec’, :modular_headers => false
```

I left out React and React-Core as these are the modules being redefiend in the first place.

Comment: It doesn't work. No diff.

Comment: It doesn't work for me either, I posted an answer that worked for me but it was deleted by https://stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf